# Form button not sending its name-value

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I'm generating a little form consisting of a single button using javascript and when the form submits the backend isn't getting any data.

Code to generate the form:

```js
let form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = "<%=application.getContextPath() + "/MyAds"%>";
form.method = "POST";

let buttonPublish = document.createElement("button");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("name", "status");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("type", "submit");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("value", "publish-" + post.id);
buttonPublish.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary", "btn-primary", "btn-fixed-size-100");
buttonPublish.innerText = "Publish";
                        
form.appendChild(buttonPublish);
div.appendChild(form);
```

Resulting HTML:

```html
<form action="/p3/MyAds" method="POST">
    <button name="status" type="submit" value="publish-13" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-size-100">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Backend (Java Servlet):

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("status")); //<-- Prints null
    if (request.getAttribute("status") != null) {
        // Not implemented yet
    }
    else {              
        // ...
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a text input to the form and I wasn't receiving that value either so I think the problem isn't the button itself but something related to the form.

**EDIT:** As @epascarello pointed out in a comment I was using the wrong function. Replacing getAttribute with getParameter fixed it.

Comment: Isn't it `getParameter`?

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid, thanks for pointing it out. I was ready to waste the whole night fixing that because I gotta upload this assignment tomorrow.